# Заполнить вектор с помощью итераторов с возрастающими значениями и измерить время

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Код:

```
start = clock();
for (int i = 0; first != last; ++i)
{
    *first = i;
    first++;
}
finish = clock();
res = finish - start;
cout << "Цикл с итераторами:" << res << "ms" << endl;
```

Код вроде нормальный (не уверен в этом). Но алгоритм выполняется за 0 мс. Как это исправить?
Размер вектора = 100000000;

Comment: Ну а какая длина этого вектора? Если небольшая, то может и правда 0 в миллисек?

Comment: Кстати, чтобы корректно перевести из процессорного времени в мс надо res поделить на CLOCKS_PER_SEC а потом умножить на 1000

Comment: если вектор просто заполняется, но потом не используется, компилятор может совсем выбросить его заполнение. И будет 0 мс

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, можно повторить эти же действия в цикле несколько сотен/тысяч раз.

И заодно воспользоваться не тормознутым `clock()`, а [`high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

И еще - [Гантерот](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-6-7.html) вам в помощь, у него этот вопрос рассмотрен более-менее подробно.